# System.Web.HttpFileCollection is not marked as serializable

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, properties

While i debug the following code for uploading a file i am getting the following error.

The code is

```
  if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
            objStatusData.SaveAttachments = Request.Files;
        else
            objStatusData.SaveAttachments = null;
```

objStatusData is an object of the property class named as StatusData which is serialized like this

```
[Serializable]
public class StatusData
```

But i am getting this error.

> Type 'System.Web.HttpFileCollection' in Assembly 'System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is not marked as serializable.   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitSerialize(Object obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context, SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter, ObjectWriter objectWriter)

How can i avoid this issue. Please help me by suggesting some needful steps.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: My Guess is the Property SaveAttachments is of type System.Web.HttpFileCollection, this one is not serializable, so the error is correct.

If you want to serialize it use a property that consumes whatever you need of your Request.Files.

For example a List and fill it with all keys in your HttpFileCollection, or you make a custom class that inherits from HttpFileCollection and make it serializable by yourself

Comment: Yes You are right Visions. Can you please elaborate how can we resolve this issue.

Comment: what information of the httpfilecollection do you need? only the keys or do you need a dictionary with keys and the items? or even more?

Comment: dictionary with keys and the items

Comment: since serializing the stream seems pretty useless too me i would guess you only need the filename of the HttpPostedFile or do you need more? HttpPostedFile, too, is not serializable, so you need to make a serializable class consuming all propterties u need to serialize, or implementing the ISerializable Interface in your class